# Dynamic Linking to Boost DLLs

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2015

In a single Visual Studio 2015 solution, I have a WPF application, a C++/CLI DLL that 'wraps' a native C++ project (that compiles to a static LIB).  All was working great until:

I added Boost Log to the native C++ project.  Everything happy compiles but I get a BadFormatException with a message '<> is not a valid Win32 application' when attempting to run the WPF application.

I found in another answer here that I needed to change to use the DLL versions of Boost and added 'BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK'.  I have also confirmed that both the C++/CLI and native C++ projects are set to compile to Win32 and that WPF project compiles to x86.

If I leave the native C++ project as a LIB, everything compiles but I still get the same BadFormatException.  I have copied the required Boost DLLs to the WPF application Debug directory (I used BOOST_LIB_DIAGNOSTIC to confirm which libraries I needed).

If I change the native C++ project to a DLL, it compiles but the C++/CLI project no longer links because it can't find the LIB file (shouldn't it now be looking for a DLL?).

1. Should the native C++ project now be a DLL? If so, how do I get the C++/CLI project to link correctly?
2. Or should it work if I leave the native C++ project as LIB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I recall:

1. Even to link DLL you need LIB file, this LIB file is produced along with DLL, and contains references to the DLL.
2. Static linking with some boost libraries won't work in C++/CLI because they will rely on static TLS (thread local storage). Boost.Thread known to have this dependency, and Boost.Log probably uses Boost.Thread. If you have single-threaded code, you may try BOOST_LOG_NO_THREADS.

Comment: Thanks Alexander.  After some reading I need to actually mark all the classes in the native C++ project as 'exportable' and the compiler will then generate a lib file. I think this was the crucial missing step.  I'll try that over the next couple days.

Comment: Should it be possible to leave my native C++ project as a static lib but link dynamically to Boost?  I've run into problems exporting the classes to make a DLL as there is extensive use of the std library in the class interaces (ie. std::vector, std::unique_ptr, std::string). Or do I need to investigate other logging libraries that I am able to statically link to?

Comment: Yes, it should be possible to have boost as dynamic library used by static library.
Regarding std classes used in interfaces. Using dynamic runtime library (i.e. /MD for release /MDd for debug) in all the parts solves such problems.

Comment: I've checked the compiler command arguments and it is definitely using /MDd but still errors that the std::* classes in the interface need to be marked as exportable.  I'll try again at having my library be a static lib.

Comment: Finally figured it out.  It nows works as a static LIB.  I needed to define 'BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK' in the C++/CLI project compiler settings as well.  Thanks for your help.